# sleep function in while statement

Tags: c

I can't understand why this code does not print current time in every one second. 
What is the problem here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        time_t tm;
        struct tm *t_struct;
        tm = time(NULL);
        t_struct = localtime(&tm);

        printf("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", t_struct->tm_hour, t_struct->tm_min, t_struct->tm_sec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Levon, why would you do that?

Comment: @Levon it doesn't matter - that is what the compiler is for. It will automatically pull the declarations out of the loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stdout` may be line buffered, so you might need to either `fflush` it after outputting text, or print a newline to make changes visible.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to display current time in single line instead of multiple ?

Comment: @rogi, it really depends on your run environment; however, you could try using `fflush(stdout)` (to display the current time) and then printing the carriage return character `'\r'` before printing a new time.